# When apk don't exist on my server on android

Tags: android

```
public void getServerApk() {
Uri mUri = Uri.parse(Url);   //Uri == my server domain
DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(mUrl);
r.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "my.apk");
r.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
dm.enqueue(r);
```

and when Download finish my.apk...

```
private BroadcastReceiver apkReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      try {
      String InstallCommand,RebootCommand;

      InstallCommand = "pm install -r /sdcard/Download/my.apk";
      RebootCommand = "reboot";
      Process Insproc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", InstallCommand});
      Insproc.waitFor();

      Process Rebootproc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", RebootCommand});
      Rebootproc.waitFor();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
   };
```

this code will work if apk exist on my server. this is normal operation

but when Apk doesn't exist on my server, not exist apk.  only reboot.

I want if Apk doesn't exist. `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`
    execute.

How can i execute below code when Apk doesn't exist on my server.`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` on android programmatically?

Comment: how does your Receiver get called? which action(s) it listens to? and who sends/broadcast those actions?

Comment: `@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter apkcompleteFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        registerReceiver(apkcompleteReceiver, apkcompleteFilter);
    }`

Comment: when you get that action, you can create `File` instance on the apk path `/sdcard/Download/my.apk` then make sure it's exist, and check it's `size > 0` or some other size, if all is good, then start executing your commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's what i mean (to check file exist, and file size is good)
change the code in your `onReceive()` method as following :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        //------START add this code -------
        File apkFile = new File("/sdcard/Download/my.apk");

        //length is file size in bytes, use other size if you want, like (minimum size)
        //(apkFile.length < 512000) where 512000 byte = 500KB, this will mean file size should be at least 500KB
        if(!apkFile.exists() || apkFile.length <= 0){ 
            //download failed
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            return;
        }
        //------END add this code -------

        String InstallCommand,RebootCommand;

        InstallCommand = "pm install -r /sdcard/Download/my.apk";
        RebootCommand = "reboot";
        Process Insproc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", InstallCommand});
        Insproc.waitFor();

        Process Rebootproc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", RebootCommand});
        Rebootproc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps, what I coding registerReceiver?

Comment: @조현욱 i have updated the answer to make it clear, which lines to add to your code